# Fill a dropdown list with query result from php table

Tags: php, html, sql

I've been trying to populate a dropdown list with results from a query using php from a mysql table but the list is empty. Could someone please take a look at my code and tell me what it is that  I'm doing wrong.

My query is `Select cat from kernel`

I used the code : `$results = $query->fetchAll();`

Heres my code:

```
<?php

$dbhandle = new PDO('host','username','password');


$sql = "SELECT cat FROM kernel";
$results = $query->fetchAll();

echo "<select name='cat'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['cat'] . "'>" . $row['cat'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: are there results in your query? If so you're going to need to post a lot more code before we can help.

Comment: What does $results return ?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327235/populate-dropdown-with-mysql-query-results-php-mysql

Comment: Is your query already working? 
Nobody will solve your problem entirely.. you must provide more information!

I Suggest you to google a litle bit more! :P

Comment: you're off to a good start, now do something with the results. :)

Comment: I've updated my question. Been googling for like 2 hours and couldn't get it to work :)

Comment: it says undefined value: dbh and Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object. Pleae help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$sth = $dbhandle->prepare("SELECT cat FROM kernel");
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<select name='cat'>";
foreach($results as $row) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['cat'] . "'>" . $row['cat'] . "</option>";
}    
echo "</select>";

?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Thanks it worked! there is an extra bracket close at the line: "$results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));" which should be "$results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);"